# Avoid yes or no prompts in wbadmin script

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, tasks

I have created script for deleting old backups with 
`wbadmin delete backup -keepVersions:10`
and scheduled task to run with task scheduler. But this task scheduler is not working as this command prompts for Yes or no. How can i skip that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin-delete-systemstatebackup) Article, you just need to add `-quiet` to your command.

```
wbadmin delete backup -keepVersions:10 -quiet
```

> -quiet:   Runs the subcommand with no prompts to the user.

Comment: I just saw that this documentation is about `wbadmin start`, not about `wbadmin delete`. Please still try it, it might work.

Comment: `wdadmin delete` also has `-quiet` flag.  You just need to change the link in your answer to this one : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin-delete-systemstatebackup

Comment: @Nuhus great! Can you accept this answer by clicking the check mark icon next to the answer? Then others will know this question has been solved